# Not able to install any software on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management, bashrc

I tried to install MatLAB in the directory

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
```

and add this path to `.bashrc`.
After this, I was able to launch Matlab by just typing Matlab in bash.

But now, when I try to install any other **package using apt package manager**, I get an error and this message pops up in the terminal.

When I press the OK button, it asked me to enter the location where Matlab is installed.
So I entered the path

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab
```

But it didn't work. Then I moved all files of Matlab from

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
```

to

```
/opt/matlab
```

and entered the path `/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab` again.
But it didn't work, again. I also have removed the export path line from `~.bashrc`, but it is not working.

I also restored the `~.bashrc` from `/etc/skel` but this didn't work either.

The main issue is that, I am not able to install any package.
For example, when I type `sudo apt install kazam`, I get the error explained above.

Comment: Does it work with `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab -desktop`. What error message do you have?

Comment: Nothing in your question contains output from `apt`, but you've referenced errors in apt twice. We will need that diagnostic info.  Please edit your question and include the whole output as well as the exact command you used.  Also edit your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Copy/paste exactly, do not manipulate the output and please use code fences so the data can be parsed. You can do this with three backticks on the line before and three backticks on the line after each pasted output. See: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code